# Standardization of variables in Bayesian model

Tags: bayesian, model, standardization, quadratic-form

I'm running a model to understand the relationship between children education expenditures and income.  I have three variables

- $y$ the response variable that represents the proportion of income spent with children education
- $x_1$ represents family income in dollars
- $x_2$ number of sons

I'm running a beta regression model with a bayesian approach.  The scatterplot of $y\times x_2$ suggests that a quadratic term should be used.

So I'm thinking about fit the following model and then made some variable selection

$$y=b_0+b_1x_1+b_2x_2+b_3x_2^2+b_4x_1x_2$$

In some post here, I read that in cases where is polynomial term, standardization should be done.

When I do standardization, I should do it with $y$,$x_1$ and $x_2$ or only with $x_2$?

The variable $x_2$ have discrete values $(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)$ should it be standardized?

The response variable need to be standardized?

Comment: The risk is multicollinearity. Mean-center (or standardize) both x1 and x2. [https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/279777/131407](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/279777/131407)

Comment: @RoseHartman I don't need to standardize  the response variable $y$?

Comment: No, you don't need to, but you can if you want to. It won't make any meaningful difference.